# How to know the type of object in list?

Tags: c#

I created a list in C# with two object type, and I need to show the object with type `ClientPhysique`. `ClientPhysique` and `ClientMoral` extend the `Client` class.

```
public List<Client> Clients = new List<Client>();

#region Methodes
// Ajouter un Client:
public void Ajouter()
{
    ClientPhysique CP = new ClientPhysique("EE111111", "Ahmed", "Yassine", 1, 06020202, "Rue Gmasa, Marrakech, 40000");
    ClientMorale CM = new ClientMorale("A1414", "Rue mhamid, A6, Marrakech, 40160", 12121212, 1000000, 6, 06060606, "Titwan de Titwan");
    Clients.Add(CP);
    Clients.Add(CM);
}
```

Comment: `item.GetType().Name`?

Comment: "ClientPhysique and ClientMoral extend the Client class." Then you alllready know that there are only instances of `Cleint`-class in your list, don´t you? So what´s your question?

Comment: I didn't write full code. Item represents an item inside list. @HimBromBeere

Answer (score 4):

You can narrow down your list with the LINQ Method `OfType`. It allows you to iterate the list items with a specific type, ignoring all other items:

```
foreach(ClientPhysique item in Clients.OfType<ClientPhysique>()) {
    //Do something with your item
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use Oftype as follows

```
var result = Clients.OfType<ClientPhysique>();
    foreach (var element in result)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot.